# How to handle clients who are both sender and receiver at the same time in UDP broadcast

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

I am stuck in the following situation: I have 2 written programs `server.c` and `client.c`. What these 2 aim to do at the end is to simulate a chatting app, similar to the one found in [Beej's guide](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Edanr/courses/6761/Fall00/hw/pa1/6761-sockhelp.pdf) (section 6.2, page 34). However, I do something different. In my case the server just accepts new connections (with TCP) and whenever a new client connects/disconnects the server will send a message to all the other still connected clients and notify them. Again, the clients are connected to the server by TCP.

The server doesn't receive the clients' messages to then send them to all the other clients. No. In my case, what I want to do is have the clients communicate directly, without the messages first going to the server. I want to do this by using UDP broadcast in each of the clients. So basically, once a client connects to the server that client is done communicating with the server until it will decide to disconnect. Until then this client will only be able to **send UDP broadcast** messages or **receive UDP broadcast** messages, without interacting with the server.

The problem I have is that I don't have a port to use in the `client.c` code. I can set the `sin_family` to `AF_INET`, I can set the IP address to the broadcast LAN address (ending in `255`), but I cannot set a port when creating the broadcast `struct sockaddr_in` in the `client.c` code. You see, I am running multiple instances of this program `client.c` on my machine. I should be able to do this because the server is on my machine and the client is on a virtual machine so I can run multiple instances of `client.c` in parallel since even tough they will have the same IP address, they will have different ports.

But I can't `bind()` the broadcast socket to a port in the `client.c` code. It will bind on the first run of my program, but at the second run it will see that the port is used and it will throw an error. Even if this would've worked, somewhere in the program I need to send a message using the `sendto()` command and here I have to specify where I want to send it. Now there is no way around knowing the port. But I cannot know it, since each run of the program will have a different port unless I choose one and bind it. But I cannot choose one either, since in that case I won't be able to run multiple instances of the program because the second run would result in an error.

Is there a way to get around this? A way to send a broadcast message in the LAN without needing to bind to a port. And this should be done in such a way that other clients can see what was sent through broadcast in the LAN while also not knowing the port from which the message was sent. I know I can use `select` to both read and write at the same time, but I can't get to the stage where I select since I can't assign ports to my clients. So I didn't get there yet. It basically comes down to having multiple clients, and these clients can **send UDP broadcast messages** and **receive UDP broadcast** messages at the same time, without having a server to orchestrate them. The problem is these clients have no port to work with.

Comment: If you had multiple clients on a single host listening on different ports (or even on the same port using SO_REUSEPORT), how do you expect the networking stack to know to multiplex packets to all clients? That's not how any operating system handles network packets.

Comment: Since you have multiple VMs running `client.c`, you can set all your VM's IP addresses to be different. Then they can all listen on the same port. So if your code is, say programmed to listen on port 8080. If all your VMs have a different IP address, they will be able to bind to the socket. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can `bind()` multiple UDP sockets to the same port as long as you set the `SO_REUSEADDR` and (under OS's that support it) `SO_REUSEPORT` options on the socket first:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

const int trueValue = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &trueValue, sizeof(trueValue));
#ifdef __APPLE__
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &trueValue, sizeof(trueValue));
#endif

// then go on to bind() the socket, using the same (fixed) port number for every client
```

Once you have this done you can create multiple clients on the same host (e.g. for testing) and they will all receive each others' broadcast-packets (and IIRC also they will also receive the broadcast-packets they sent themselves, so be ready for that).

Side note:  if your plan is to have clients communicating with each other directly and never interacting with the server, then you might as well get rid of the server as it doesn't sound like you need it for anything(?)